# ¿Cómo hacer que al generar el elemento audio y lo reproduzca?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría arreglar este script, para que al momento de que genere el elemento audio lo reproduzca. ya intente de todo y no me funciona.

```
// Ajax
function ScriptRequest(url, callback) {
ScriptRequest.handler = function(data) {
callback(data);
}

url += (url.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=ScriptRequest.handler';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = script.onerror = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
}

document.body.appendChild(script);
script.src = url;
}

function play_audio(aid) {
if (typeof play_audio.now != 'undefined') {
    if (play_audio.now == aid) return;

    var el = document.querySelector('[data-id="'+play_audio.now+'"] audio');
    el.pause();
    el.currentTime = 0;
    el.style.display = "none";
    el.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
}

var audio = document.querySelector('[data-id="'+aid+'"] audio')
if (audio != null) {
    audio.style.display = "block";
    audio.play();
} else {
    var url = 'https://api.vk.com//method/audio.getById.json?audios='+aid+'&access_token='+vk_access_token;
    ScriptRequest(url, function(data) {
        audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.controls = audio.autoplay = true;
        document.querySelector('[data-id="'+aid+'"]').appendChild(audio);
        audio.setAttribute('src', data.response[0].url);

        audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            var el = document.querySelector('[data-id="'+aid+'"]').nextElementSibling;
            if (el != null) {
                play_audio(el.getAttribute('data-id'));
            }
        }, true);
    });
}
document.querySelector('[data-id="'+aid+'"]').style.backgroundColor = "#efefef";
play_audio.now = aid;
}

// Set events to play link
window.onload = function() {
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.search-result a.play');
for (var i = 0, il = links.length; i < il; ++i) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
play_audio((this.parentElement).getAttribute('data-id'));
        event.preventDefault();
    }, true);
}
}
```

De antemano gracias. :)

Comment: La app encuentra el audio? Te dá algún error en concreto? Puedes postearlo? Quizas te pueda ayudar este hilo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo mínimo y completo? Es muy difícil encontrar el error cuando sólo se tiene parte de la información. ¿Aparece algún error en la consola de JS?¿qué es play_audio.now?

Comment: El script no me da ningun error, genera el elemento audio perfectamente e incluso le añade perfectamente el sonido pero no me lo reproduce. y eso es lo que quiero lograr que al momento de que genere el audio me lo reproduzca pero no lo hace aqui les dejo un ejemplo http://mp3dl.es.cx/q:linkin+park

Answer (score 2):

Todo es cuestion de .load() y .play(), que tal una funcion asi:

```
    function play(link_del_archivo, audio){
        audio.src = link_del_archivo.attr('href');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

aqui hay un ejemplo bastante descriptivo [Reproducir mp3 con javascript](http://ricardogeek.com/como-crear-un-playlist-de-audio-con-javascript/)